# The characteristic values of the p-th compound matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\mathfrak{A_p}$ is the p-th compound matrix of A, May you please explain what's going on here?

[image]
[image]

I can follow until $$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_{k_1}^{(m)} \lambda_{k_2}^{(m)} \dots \lambda_{k_p}^{(m)} = \lambda_{k_1} \lambda_{k_2} \dots \lambda_{k_p}$$ But after that, I don't understand what the author mean.

Comment: Let me get this right: the 'characteristic values' of $A$ are its eigenvalues, and the $p$-compound is the kronecker product of $p$ copies of $A$?

Comment: @Exodd The 'characteristic values' of $A$ are its eigenvalues, yes. The p-th compound matrix (p-the multiplicative compound matrix) is an ${n \choose p} \times {n \choose p}$ matrix formed from all $p \times p$ minors of $A$, arranged with the submatrix index sets in lexicographic order. Is this clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a complex $n$-dimensional vector space. What I get out of this in modern language is that:

- the linear transformations $V\to V$ with $n$ distinct eigenvalues are [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) in the space of all linear transformations,
- the map taking a linear transformation $A:V\to V$ to its [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of eigenvalues is [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) (in [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance), say),
- the map taking a linear transformation $A:V\to V$ to its $p$th [exterior power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Functoriality) $\bigwedge^p A:\bigwedge^p V \to \bigwedge^p V$ is also continuous (the author uses $\mathfrak{A}_p$ and "compound matrix" for this latter concept), and
- if a linear transformation $A:V\to V$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then the eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^p A:\bigwedge^p V\to \bigwedge^p V$ are given by all products of $p$-element subsets of the set of eigenvalues of $A$.

Consequently, the author concludes that for *any* linear transformation $A$ (whose eigenvalues need not be distinct), the eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^p A:\bigwedge^p V\to \bigwedge^p V$ are given by all products of $p$-element sub-multisets of the multiset of eigenvalues of $A$ (accounting properly for multiplicity). To draw this conclusion, the author uses density and continuity to reduce to the case of $n$ distinct eigenvalues for which the result has already been proven.

Comment: +1; thanks for your answer :). However, some words you use are unfamiliar for me. So, please, bear with me! Recheck my understanding: In simple words, taking all possible products of the e-vals of an $A_{m}$ will give a complete system of e-vals for the corresponding  $\mathfrak{A}_{(m)p}$ (as proven before), the sequence of all of which will , in turn, give a complete system of e-vals for $\mathfrak{A}_{p}$. But taking all possible products of the e-vals (eigenvalues) of every $A_m$ is the same as taking all possible products of the e-vals of $A$; therefore the theorem follows. Is this right?

Comment: @AbduMagdy : I think your summary is correct. I just want to emphasize that "the sequence of all of which will , in turn, give a complete system of e-vals for $\mathfrak{A}_p$" because getting eigenvalues and finding the "compound matrix" are continuous operations, and "taking all possible products of the e-vals (eigenvalues) of every $A_m$ is the same as taking all possible products of the e-vals of $A$" because 'taking all products of the e-vals' is also a continuous operation.